# Race-condition when submitting form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

I have to do a hack in order to be able to submit a form (non-ajax) using jQuery.

If I don't do the `if` statement the form won't submit:

#### This works (Form gets submitted)

```
$("#myHiddenFieldID").val(JSON.stringify(jsObject));
var x = $("#myHiddenFieldID").val();
if (x) {
    $("#myHiddenForm").submit();
}
```

#### This doesn't work (form does not get submitted field stays empty)

```
$("#myHiddenFieldID").val(JSON.stringify(jsObject));
var x = $("#myHiddenFieldID").val();
// I used to put an alert here, which was shown __before__ the text appeared in the text field???!!! 
$("#myHiddenForm").submit();
```

I don't understand, why I have to read the textfields content here...

Comment: where is this code? Inside some sort of onclick handler I presume?  Also is this within a `$(document).ready(function() { });` block?

Comment: @JonTaylor seems correct. Is you form submitted unexpectedly. Can you see if there is any error in console ?

Comment: Post minimal jsfiddle to reproduce it

Comment: Perhaps this code is executed twice, adding the if(x) statement would in such case protect against the first - wrong - run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597501/), the assignment statement is executed before the value is passed to the text field:

```
var x = $("#myHiddenFieldID").val();
$("#myHiddenFieldID").val(JSON.stringify(jsObject));
$("#myHiddenForm").submit();
```