# How to increment a value in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

```
var map = {};
map[key] = value;
```

How can I

- assign value 1 if key does not yet exist in the object
- increment the value by 1 if it exists

Could I do better than:

```
if (map[key] == null) map[key] = 0;
map[key] = map[key]++;
```

Comment: Try if (typeof map [key] === "undefined") to check for inexistence. Normally something that doesnt exist in your map will be undefined. Not null.

Comment: Can't you just use `hasOwnProperty` to check for the existence of the prop you are looking for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Object increment item if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690814/javascript-object-increment-item-if-not-exist)

Answer (score 55):

Here you go minimize your code.

```
map[key] = (map[key]+1) || 1 ;
```

Comment: By "flag hoisting" you mean "short-circuit evaluation". This doesn't have anything to do with hoisting, although "flag hoisting" is an amusing conflation.

Comment: without having flag hoisting property in JavaScript. You can not use so called "short-circuit evaluation". Ultimately, Its utilizing the same concept.

Comment: you can call it variable hoisting .

Comment: There is no kind of hoisting involved in your code at all.

Comment: check the first answer :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597501/which-design-patterns-take-advantage-of-javascripts-hoisting-behavior

Comment: You're misreading that question. `var a = a || 1;` would involve hoisting because of the `var` keyword (the local variable is hoisted). Here you're manipulating a property of an existing object, therefore there's nothing that would get hoisted anywhere.

Comment: this is how hoisting works :

map[key] = (map[key]+1) || 1 ; it will break down in two statement 

var map[key] = undefined; /

map[key] = (undefined+1) || 1; // outuput =1

if no variable hoisitng  then this will give syntax error saying map[key] is not defined

Comment: @ricky: nope. Getting a value by non-existing key returns `undefined` (without any invisible assignment). `undefined + 1` gives NaN, which is a falsey value, so the control goes to `|| 1` part. I assure you nothing is being hoisted here. Go read up on the term.

Comment: @ricky: also multiline code is impossible to read in comments. Looks much better as a link to gist or pastebin or whatever. That way you can have syntax highlighting too :)

Comment: @Sergio: I agree with your explanation. In this case i am wrong if  the variable would have direct object then my concept will apply.

Comment: @ricky: "error saying map[key] is not defined". `map` IS defined. And `map[key]` is not an identifier.

Comment: Breaks when existing value is -1. Then map[key]+1 is 0 which is falsy so overall result of the increment is 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Better: `map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + 1` as in [How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690820/1157324)

Answer (score 18):

Recently it could be

```
map[key] = (map[key] ?? 0) + 1;
```

[Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the object doesn't have the specific key and set it or increase existing key value by one:

```js
function assignKey(obj, key) {
  typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' ? obj[key] = 1 : obj[key]++;
}

var map = {};

assignKey(map, 2);
assignKey(map, 2);
assignKey(map, 4);
assignKey(map, 1);
assignKey(map, 2);
assignKey(map, 5);
assignKey(map, 1);
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 5):

ES6 provides a dedicated class for maps, [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). You can easily extend it to construct a "map with a default value":

```js
class DefaultMap extends Map {

    constructor(defVal, iterable=[]) {
        super(iterable);
        this.defVal = defVal;
    }

    get(key) {
        if(!this.has(key))
            this.set(key, this.defVal);
        return super.get(key);
    }
}

m = new DefaultMap(9);
console.log(m.get('foo'));
m.set('foo', m.get('foo') + 1);
console.log(m.get('foo'))
```

(Ab)using Objects as Maps had several disadvantages and requires some caution.

Comment: The code snippet has an error; `Uncaught SecurityError`. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the code itself or with some StackOverflow issue. Just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 3):

you can use ternory operator like this

```js
 map[key] ? map[key]++ : map[key] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you convert array's value into integer and increment it. It will be robust code.
By default array's value is string. so in case you do not convert it to integer then it might not work cross browser.

```
if (map[key] == null) map[key] = 0;
map[key] = parseInt(map[key])+1;
```

Comment: `parseInt(undefined)` is NaN.

Comment: have you also declared value of key ?

Comment: Also, "by default array's value is string" is just rubbish, and there are no arrays in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addToMap(map, key, value) {
    if (map.has(key)) {       
        map.set(key, parseInt(map.get(key), 10) + parseInt(value, 10));
    } else {
        map.set(key, parseInt(value, 10));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an object:

```
    tagObject = {};
    tagObject['contentID'] = [];  // adding an entry to the above tagObject
    tagObject['contentTypes'] = []; // same explanation as above
    tagObject['html'] = [];
```

Now below is the occurrences entry which I am addding to the above tag Object..

**ES 2015 standards:**
`function () {}`  is same as `() => {}`

```
          let found = Object.keys(tagObject).find(
                (element) => {
                    return element === matchWithYourValueHere;
                });

          tagObject['occurrences'] = found ? tagObject['occurrences'] + 1 : 1;
```

this will increase the count of a particular object key..

Answer (score 0):

The shortest code would be:

`map[key] = ++map[key] || 1`