# Shorthand syntax to push or create item to array, at certain key of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an object of the following type:

```
type ObjectOfArrays = {
    [id: string]: Array<string>
};
```

At multiple places in my code I want to push strings to the correct array, referenced by the `id`.
Currently, I would have to do this in the following way:

```
if (id in obj)
    obj[id].push("text");
else
    obj[id] = ["text"];
```

Is it possible to do this in a shorter way? I understand it probably won't be as simple as an object with numbers, like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591024/17864167). However, I am curious if there are alternative notations.

Any suggestions or references are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to the other answer, using an empty array as a default and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const obj = {}

id = '4'
obj[id] = (obj[id] || []).concat(['test'])
console.log(obj)

obj[id] = (obj[id] || []).concat(['test2'])
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, hadn't thought of that. Thanks!